# delegate function does not see class object

Tags: c#, delegates

I was trying to do a delegate example by myself. The delegate name is `MaaşKarşılaştırmaDelegesi`. First, I tried to compare two objects' fields (which is "maaş") from the same class (which are either `BeyazYaka` or `MaviYaka`), it was working well. But then I wanted to compare two objects from different classes( one from `MaviYaka` and one from `BeyazYaka`) but then, inside the delegated function in the Program class, the compiler gives an error saying:

> The name 'k1' does not exist in the current context
>
> The name 'k2' does not exist in the current context

So the compiler does not see the created class objects. I think the error is in the if else block. Because when i try to remove the block and just write;

```
MaviYaka k1 = (MaviYaka)o1;

BeyazYaka k2 = (BeyazYaka)o2;
```

the error is removed. But it gives error when this is in the if block.
Can you help me why this happens?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace tekrar_delegates
{
    class MaviYaka
    {
    public int maaş;

    public MaviYaka(int maaş)
    {
        this.maaş = maaş;
    }

    public static int KiminMaaşıDahaFazla(object o1, object o2) 
    {
        MaviYaka m1 = (MaviYaka)o1;
        MaviYaka m2 = (MaviYaka)o2;

        if (m1.maaş > m2.maaş) { return 1; }
        else { return 2; }
    }

}

class BeyazYaka
{
    public int maaş;

    public BeyazYaka(int maaş)
    {
        this.maaş = maaş;
    }

    public static int KiminMaaşıDahaFazla(object o1, object o2) 
    {
        BeyazYaka b1 = (BeyazYaka)o1;
        BeyazYaka b2 = (BeyazYaka)o2;

        if (b1.maaş > b2.maaş) { return 1; }
        else { return 2; }
    }
}

class Pair
{
    private object[] thePair = new object[2];

    public Pair(object o1, object o2)
    {
        thePair[0] = o1;
        thePair[1] = o2;
    }

    public delegate int MaaşKarşılaştırmaDelegesi(object o1, object o2);

    public void Print(MaaşKarşılaştırmaDelegesi delegatedFunc)
    {
        if (delegatedFunc(thePair[0], thePair[1]) == 1) { Console.WriteLine("1.nin maaşı daha büyük."); }
        else { Console.WriteLine("2.nin maaşı daha büyük."); }
    }

}

class Program
{
    public static int KiminMaaşıDahaFazla(object o1, object o2)
    {
        if (true)
        {
            MaviYaka k1 = (MaviYaka)o1;
        }
        else { }
        if (true)
        {
            BeyazYaka k2 = (BeyazYaka)o2;
        }
        else { }

        if (k1.maaş > k2.maaş) { return 1; }
        else { return 2; }
    }



    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MaviYaka maviYaka1 = new MaviYaka(300);            

        BeyazYaka beyazYaka1 = new BeyazYaka(500);            

        Pair karışıkPair = new Pair(maviYaka1, beyazYaka1);            

        Pair.MaaşKarşılaştırmaDelegesi karışıkDelege = new Pair.MaaşKarşılaştırmaDelegesi(KiminMaaşıDahaFazla);

        karışıkPair.Print(karışıkDelege);     

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Comment: You've declared the variables `k1` and `k2` within those `if` statements. They don't exist outside the blocks they're declared in. This is just totally normal scoping - it's not about delegates at all.

Comment: Thank you very much :):)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define a variable inside an `if` block, it's scope is limited to that block of code, and it's effectively gone when that block of code ends.

To avoid this specific error, you can change your code to:

```
public static int KiminMaaşıDahaFazla(object o1, object o2)
{
    // We need to define k1 and k2 outside of the if block 
    // in order to use them outside of the if block
    MaviYaka k1 = null;
    BeyazYaka k2 = null;

    if (true)
    {
        k1 = (MaviYaka) o1;
    }
    else { }
    if (true)
    {
        k2 = (BeyazYaka) o2;
    }
    else { }

    if (k1.maaş > k2.maaş) { return 1; }
    else { return 2;}
}
```

Also, there is no point in using `if (true) { // do something } else {}`, though I assume that's there for some testing purposes, but your whole method can be simplified to one line:

```
public static int KiminMaaşıDahaFazla(object o1, object o2)
{
    return ((MaviYaka)o1).maaş > ((BeyazYaka)o2).maaş ? 1 : 2;
}
```

---

A better way to do this might be to simply check the type of `o1` and `o2` at runtime, and get the property values from the objects that way instead.

For example:

```
public static int KiminMaaşıDahaFazla(object o1, object o2)
{
    // I've assumed the type is 'int'; change to the correct type if needed
    int k1_maaş = 0;
    int k2_maaş = 0;

    // Check the type of object and assign our variables as appropriate
    if (o1 is MaviYaka) k1_maaş = ((MaviYaka) o1).maaş;
    else if (o1 is BeyazYaka) k1_maaş = ((BeyazYaka) o1).maaş;

    if (o2 is MaviYaka) k1_maaş = ((MaviYaka) o2).maaş;
    else if (o2 is BeyazYaka) k1_maaş = ((BeyazYaka) o2).maaş;

    return k1_maaş > k2_maaş ? 1 : 2;
}
```

---

Another option is to create an interface that has the common properties between the two classes, implement the interface on both classes, and then have this method take in two arguments of the interface type:

For example:

```
public interface ICommonYaka
{
    int maaş { get; set; }
}
public class MaviYaka : ICommonYaka
{
    public int maaş { get; set; }
}
public class BeyazYaka : ICommonYaka
{
    public int maaş { get; set; }
}
```

Now we can write our method like this, and can pass either a `MaviYaka` or `BeyazYaka` type (or any other class that implements `ICommonYaka`) to either argument:

```
public static int KiminMaaşıDahaFazla(ICommonYaka o1, ICommonYaka o2)
{
    return o1.maaş > o2.maaş ? 1 : 2;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Rufus, i was actually trying to put some conditioning into the if statements. But after some debugging effort, i changed the if conditioning to true :) So, what i actually wanted is, check the run-time types of objects o1 and o2 inside the method, and assign them to the related class objects. One example is;

Comment: That's what I thought, which is why I added the last example :).  Another option is to create an `interface` that has the common properties between the two classes, implement the interface on both classes, and then have this method take in two arguments of the interface type

Comment: I updated the answer to include an example of using a common interface.

Comment: May be silly but how can i include code in this comment ?

Comment: Surround it with the backtic character `( \` )`. For more information see [how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: `           MaviYaka k1 = null;
            BeyazYaka k2 = null;

            if (o1.GetType() == typeof(MaviYaka))
            {
                k1 = (MaviYaka)o1;
            }
            else { }
            if (o2.GetType() == typeof(BeyazYaka))
            {
                k2 = (BeyazYaka)o2;
            }
            else { }
            if (k1.maaş > k2.maaş) { return 1; }
            else { return 2; }`
one example. i am trying to make conditioning on run time types of o1 and o2. because there will be a lot of classes (i mean other than that of Maviyaka and BeyazYaka)

Comment: You have a space after the backtick. Do all the classes have a common set of properties that you're comparing?

Comment: `MaviYaka k1 = null;
            BeyazYaka k2 = null;

            if (o1.GetType() == typeof(MaviYaka))
            {
                k1 = (MaviYaka)o1;
            }
            else { }
            if (o2.GetType() == typeof(BeyazYaka))
            {
                k2 = (BeyazYaka)o2;
            }
            else { }
            if (k1.maaş > k2.maaş) { return 1; }
            else { return 2; }`

Comment: No no, this is just an example, i have the "maaş" private integer for all the classes.

Comment: Yes, I saw the code and asked another question (and  you can `Edit` your comment instead of leaving a new one)

Comment: So why are you doing this? What does the method do that forces you to write such cumbersome code?

Comment: The method is the delegated function, i think you  can see it in the first post. I created the delegate, passed in two objects and want it to compare "maaş" and return and integer. That's it.

Comment: I'm confused. I asked "Do all the classes have a common set of properties that you're comparing?" and you said "No no, this is just an example". But now you say that you're comparing a common property? Anyway, I would recommend using the interface example or the second one I posted.

Comment: Actually i wanted to say yes :) I said "maaş" is common in every class but it is not property. I created it as a field. Anyway i think we solved the problem thanks for your effort

Comment: Ok. If it's private I guess you'll have to use reflection to get to it.